# LinkedIn Login Dialog for iPad

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, linkedin-api

Is this login UI the only one available? The [docs](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/authentication) aren't specific to iPhone or even smartphone apps yet this seems to be explicitly for smartphones. Is there an alternative UI for iPad for example? Is it possible to create your own or is this somehow prohibited?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this is the only available login UI:

http://developer.linkedin.com/forum/linkedin-authentication-through-api