# iPad: Linkedin API in iPad is not resizing to a bigger login view

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiwebview, linkedin-api

[image]

As you can see in the above image, there is a major part of the screen which is grey and unused. I want the login view to be more bigger to fill out major part of the screen rather than displaying a gray background.

The problem lies with the fact that this is a webview and we are loading the following Linkedin URL in the webview:

https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=509f2231-b1bc-42fb-874f-f6963a447dc3&auth_token_secret=20136199-7dc9-4e81-9cc9-ef1ea797b6de

I tried to find out solution through google and also Developer Linkedin but still didn't get a solution

How can we resize the view to be bigger than what it is currentlly?

Any Suggestions is appreciated.

For your Information, I have already gone through this application:

[LinkedIn Login Dialog for iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14140638/linkedin-login-dialog-for-ipad) but I want to know that if there is anything possible now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this was a webpage opening in a webView there was no other method I found (except the below mentioned one) by which I could make the content of a webpage bigger.

**Solution:**

I did it using JavaScript.

Here is the solution, I had applied to make the login dialog bigger:

```
if([CommonMethods isiPad])
{
    [self->webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.style.zoom = 1.39;"];
}
```

CommonMethods.m

```
+ (BOOL) isiPad {
#if (__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 30200)
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] respondsToSelector: @selector(userInterfaceIdiom)])
        return ([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad);
#endif
    return NO;
}
```

By this method I made the login dialog bigger in iPad.

Answer (score 1):

Check the API it may have some .xib file which is supportable for iphone versions.

Comment: Erik I want this to work for iPad and not for iPhone. I want the login view (Inner light gray box) to be bigger for iPad. Can you please help me with it?

Comment: its simple, just create new xib for iPad and just do what ever did in Linkedin API xib (iPhone) file. That means connecting the views

Comment: I want to resize the website that opens under the webview.